# how to upload file php through jquery and smarty

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

i need to upload a file doc or pdf or rich text through jquery and smarty

i try to pass the file in jquery is given below

```
window.location.href= sitePath+'download?p='+$('#file').val();
```

but the p doesn't have value. how to get the file path or name and how can stored in server

in controller i write just pass the query to model is given below

```
$model=new download();
$id=$model->upload($param);
```

and i can't develop the model code....

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send files like that.

You should either submit a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` or use some AJAX uploader (which uses form submit to iframe and then stores a file using PHP script).

**EDIT:** Some references

- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp - tutorial on how to upload a file using PHP
- http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ - example of ajax uploader.

**EDIT2:** The problem is not with your model code but with the way you try to submit a file.

Comment: give a small suggestion in form action how can i call the controller my controller name is download.